# How do we update an existing XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an existing xml file which I want to update.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            // Load the xml document for reading
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFS = ISF.OpenFile(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                XDocument file= XDocument.Load(ISFS);
                //Edit the file
                file.Save(ISFS);
            }
        }
```

The problem is whenever I use `file.Save(ISFS)`, and then try to load it again, using same method, an error is reported

```
  System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232000
  Message=Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 25, position 14.
```

UPDATE :

Here's the file after saving

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
   <AB ID="0">
       <NickName>Dummy</NickName>
   </AB>
</A><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
   <AB ID="0">
       <NickName>Dummy</NickName>
   </AB>
   <AB ID="1">
       <NickName>My1</NickName>
   </AB>
</A>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408262/adding-new-xelement-appends-entire-xml-file-to-existing-file-when-saved) was very helpful.

Comment: I have a workaround. Since I don't get a part of the document but the whole document itself, so I delete the old document and create a new file. There's an extra overhead of deleting and writing of the file and also risk of losing data if the app crashes after deleting but before creating the file.

Comment: you can just merge all and new